# Two Dojo stores, two target URLs, same DB on the server: two different stores?

Tags: rest, dojo, store

On the server, I define a hash which includes all the stores available.
E.g.:

```
stores  = {
    "workspaces": {"target":"\/workspaces\/","idProperty":"_id","sortParam":"sortBy"},
    "workspaceUsers": {"target":"\/workspaces\/:workspaceId\/users\/","idProperty":"_id","sortParam":"sortBy"}
}
```

This is obviously generated by the server.
The client defines a function, `stores()`, which -- goes like this:

```
 stores( 'workspaceUsers', { workspaceId: 343434 } ) =>  A store with target set as /workspaces/34343434/users 
 stores( 'workspaceUsers', { workspaceId: 454545 } ) =>  ANOTHER store with target set as /workspaces/454545/users
```

The `stores()` function caches things. This means that requesting:

```
stores( 'workspaceUsers', { workspaceId: 343434 } )
```

Will return the SAME store as the previous call. The store is observable and cached.

Now my question: is this a sane way to go about it? The effects of such a solution is that `stores( 'workspaceUsers', { workspaceId: 343434 } )`  and `stores( 'workspaceUsers', { workspaceId: 343434 } )` will create two different stores with two different targets, BUT they will effectively point to the same data on the server (`workspaceId` here will act as a filter, obviously).

Do you see anything stupid in what I'm doing? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to couple the store with query parameters?

Comment: the function `stores()` has parameters which are used to define the *target*, not the query parameter. Since each store is defined by its target, I don't have a choice.